# System cannot find path specified in create phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I am following installation instructions for creating an android project using phonegap. When I give command

" {bin-path}>create {app-path} "

it is showing

" {bin-path}\create.js(68,5) WshShell.Exec: The system cannot find the path specified "

But actually create.js exists in {bin-path}

Can someone suggest why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not added the Android SDK platform and tools folders to the Environment variables. Setting environment varialbes is a fairly straight process and you can google it.

Comment: Here...I found a similar post and they also say this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724925/create-js68-5-wshshell-phonegap-android