# create.js(68, 5) WshShell. phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to Phonegap.

I am trying to create a phonegap app using the command line but I keep getting this error:

```
create.js(68, 5) WshShell. Exec: The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help to know how the command you are trying to execute looks like.

Comment: I finally figured it out. the Solution was to add the Android SDK platform and tools folders to the System variable. Thanks